# Loop through tables and columns of an Entity framework object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I have a database with name `BookLibrary` with 3 tables `Author`, `Payroll` and `Article`. I am using Entity framework to connect to database. I created a instance of it.

```
BookLibrary bookLibraryContext = new BookLibrary();
```

Now I want to cast this in a dataset (to pass dataset as a argument). How to do it?

Also by using `T4` template I want to generate all column names as a readonly string property. And to do this, I need to loop through all tables and column names inside the database (and I want to do this through my entity object `bookLibraryContext`). But I am not sure how to loop through all tables and columns of an entity object? I have searched it on google but many suggested to use Reflection for looping or directly use SQL. I want to do it through C# and I am not much familiar with Reflection.

Answer (score 2):

> Now I want to cast this in a dataset (to pass dataset as a argument). How to do it?

Manually. EF and datasets are completely different technologies and neither of them contains any support for conversion to another. So you must manually create dataset and all data tables you want to use and manually fill them from the context.

If you want to work with datasets don't use Entity framework. Use dataset directly.

> But I am not sure how to loop through all tables and columns of an entity object?

Entity object doesn't have this information. This information is hidden deep inside EF mapping which is available through `bookLibraryContext.MetadataWorkspace`. You don't need reflection to get this information. You just need to understand EDM and the way how it stores information.

Try something like this:

```
foreach (var entityType in context.MetadataWorkspace
                                  .GetItems<EntityType>(DataSpace.SSpace))
{
     string tableName = entityType.MetadataProperties
                                  .Single(m => m.Name == "Name")
                                  .Value
                                  .ToString();

     var members = (ReadOnlyMetadataCollection<EdmMember>)entityType
                                              .MetadataProperties
                                              .Single(m => m.Name == "Members")
                                              .Value;

     foreach (var columnName in members.Select(m => m.Name))
     {

     }
}
```

Comment: I created a method of this code and I called it in the load event of form. When code reaches `context.MetadataWorkspace.GetItems<EntityType>(DataSpace.SSpace)`, my form appears and rest of the code is not reached at all

Comment: Make sure that you have already used EF to query or persist data before you call this code. Otherwise `MetadataWorkspace` will not be fully initialized.